# Import CSV file into Sqlite database in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, csv, import

I want to import CSV file into my Sqlite database.

When fatching csv to NSMutableArray, my console shows me values like
rows:

{

english = english1;

german = german1;

spanish = spanish1;

}

```
 english = english2;

 french = french2;

 german = german2;

 spanish = spanish2;
```

}

english = english3;

```
 french = french3;

 german = german3;

spanish = spanish3;
```

}

rows is NSMutableArray.

how to insert it in sqlite database. Please suggest me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about simply reading the file line by line and use INSERT-Statements to fill the database with the said data?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're intrested in this csv Library:
http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/11/writing-parser-using-nsscanner-csv.html

After that just INSERT the data.

Answer (score 0):

beside parsing the CSV, I would use `[fmdb][1]` to handle all of the SQLite stuff.